# Overriding a class that does not get explicitly called

Tags: python, python-3.x

My app consists of one python file `entry_point.py` and makes a heavy use of the installed packages. I need to override the behaviour of one of the classes—say `ClassA` (which resides in one of the installed packages) with `ClassB`. `ClassA` does not get explicitly called in my `entry_point.py`.

Initially I tried defining `ClassB` in my `entry_point.py` and then doing something along the

```
path.to.the.package.with.ClassA = ClassB
```

lines in `entry_point.py`, but it did not work (because, I assume other files inside of the isntalled packages still refer to the original `ClassA` in their import statements).

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be done?

Comment: Difficult to get a starting point here. Just one thought: Everything that gets executed before you set the class, e.g. during the import of the package, will have instantiated the old class, of course.

Comment: Check out mock patching. Ex:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945870/how-to-mock-patch-a-class-imported-in-another-module